# Can image metadata taken with a camera phone be trusted?

Tags: metadata, iphone, forensics

I’m wondering how accurate the metadata is on iPhone 12 photos taken. I understand time, date, and location info is easily modified. My question relates to the phone/camera description of the device used to take the picture. I received a photo from a friend who swears he took the picture he sent me from his iPhone 12 Pro Max. However the phone/camera description said it was an iPhone 11. All other photos I have ever received from him have stated iPhone 12 Pro Max.

So does anyone know how accurate the phone/camera description is please? Can this information be incorrect? Or is he lying?

Comment: [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor)

Answer (score 3):

While it is *possible* to change the metadata to make a photo taken with, say, an iPhone 12 Pro max appear to have been taken with, say, an iPhone 11, what would be the point if your friend wants you to believe it was taken with an iPhone 12 Max?

**Why would your friend go through all of that trouble to change the EXIF if he wants you to believe it was taken with an iPhone 12 Max?**

**The most likely source of the photo was an iPhone 11.**

Maybe your friend has an iPhone 11 and has changed the EXIF info in all the other photos sent to you to make it appear they were taken with an iPhone 12 Max and forgot to do it with this one?

It's possible your friend used an iPhone 11 for this photo and forgot that it wasn't the iPhone 12 Max?

Perhaps the photo was taken before the friend upgraded from an iPhone 11 to an iPhone 12 Max, but he thinks it was taken after such an upgrade?

Could it be your friend forgot they took it with someone else's iPhone 11 and then sent the image to their iPhone 12 Max that had a dead battery and wasn't available at the time?

There are many possible scenarios that could explain why your friend thinks, or at least claims, that the image was taken with an iPhone 12 Max but it was actually taken with an iPhone 11. It could be an honest mistake. It could be an intentional deception. But either way, it's not likely that the image was taken with an iPhone 12 Max and the EXIF info was changed to show it was taken with an iPhone 11 if your friend wants you to believe it was taken with an iPhone 12 Max.

As user [osullic](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/38159/osullic) says in a comment to the question: "[Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor)."

Answer (score 2):

Meta information can be changes w/o any problem. So you can't trust it.

To reveal the camera which make the photo you will need much more sophisticated forensic instruments which **may** reveal some image artifacts, specific to the particular camera (if they exist) and detect the camera whcih make the photo.